# MySQL on update trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

So, I have a MySQL table costumer with some fields

```
table <Customers>
ID    Name    Description    State
0     Jack    waiting        0
1     Jane    complete       1
```

I want to write a trigger, which updates the State field
It needs to set the value of State to 1, if the Description
is updated and gets the value complete

So far, I've come up with this:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER customerUpdated 
    BEFORE UPDATE ON Customers
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF NEW.Description = 'completed' THEN  
    UPDATE Customers SET State = '1' WHERE id = OLD.id;
END IF;
END$$
delimiter ;
```

But I get the error:

## 1442 - Can't update table 'Customers' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to set NEW.State instead of running an UPDATE statement at all:

```
IF NEW.Description = 'completed' THEN  
   SET NEW.State = 1;
END IF
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Tank you!

Comment: @RikBauwens -- np, glad I could help!